# SubSonic 3, build dynamic or expression at runtime

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, subsonic, predicatebuilder

I have a situation where I have to dynamically build a linq query based on user selections.
If I had to dynamically generate sql I could do it this way:

```
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("SELECT * FROM products p");
        sb.AppendLine("WHERE p.CategoryId > 5");

        // these variables are not static but choosen by the user
        var type1 = true;
        var type2 = true;
        var type3 = false;

        string type1expression = null;
        string type2expression = null;
        string type3expression = null;

        if (type1)
            type1expression = "p.productType1 = true";

        if (type2)
            type2expression = "p.productType2 = true";

        if (type3)
            type3expression = "p.productType3 = true";

        string orexpression = String.Empty;
        foreach(var expression in new List<string>
               {type1expression, type2expression, type3expression})
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(orexpression) &&
                    !String.IsNullOrEmpty(expression))
                orexpression += " OR ";

            orexpression += expression;
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(orexpression))
        {
            sb.AppendLine("AND (");
            sb.AppendLine(orexpression);
            sb.AppendLine(")");
        }

        // result:

       // SELECT * FROM products p
       // WHERE p.CategoryId > 5
       // AND (
       // p.productType1 = true OR p.productType2 = true
       // )
```

Now I need to create a linq query the same way.

This works well with subsonic

```
var result = from p in db.products
             where p.productType1 == true || p.productType2 == true
             select p;
```

I tried it with PredicateBuilder http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx but that throws an exception with subsonic.

```
var query = from p in db.products
            select p;

var inner = PredicateBuilder.False<product>();
inner = inner.Or(p => p.productType1 == true);
inner = inner.Or(p => p.productType2 == true);

var result = query.Where(inner);
```

the exception that is thrown: `NotSupportedException: The member 'productType1' is not supported`
at `SubSonic.DataProviders.MySQL.MySqlFormatter.VisitMemberAccess`.

Anybody has an idea how to get this query to work:

Comment: hi SchlaWeiner, I also construct my queries the way you do. I usually use this for filtering, sorting, and paging. Do you have an elegant way to do this?

Comment: I added an example. Just follow the link provided by Devart, download the sample project and add the Dynamic.cs file to your project. You have to add `using System.Linq.Dynamic` to your code in order to use the lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) will be helpful?

Comment: Yes, that worked. I suppose there is a more statically typed solution out there, that I don't find atm. But the dynamic linq source is indeed very powerful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an usage example, as requested by geocine.
It requires Dynamic Linq.

```
        var productTypes = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
        var query = from p in db.products
                    select p;

        if (productTypes.Contains(1))
            query.Add("productType1 = @0");

        if (productTypes.Contains(2))
            query.Add("productType2 = @0");

        if (productTypes.Contains(3))
            query.Add("productType3 = @0");

        if (productTypes.Contains(4))
            query.Add("productType4 = @0");

        if (productTypes.Count > 0)
        {
            string result = String.Join(" OR ", productTypes);
            query = query.Where("(" + result + ")", true);
        }

        var result = from p in query
                     select new {Id = p.ProductId, Name = p.ProductName };
```

it looks akward but it works.